# avrisp mkii failed to enter programming mode

Tags: avr, atmega, atmelstudio

Trying to program an ATmega2560, I cannot read the device signature, fuses or program the flash. I keep getting this error:

Timestamp:  2016-03-14 19:58:01.669
Severity:       INFO
ComponentId:    20000
StatusCode: 0

Failed to enter programming mode. ispEnterProgMode: Error status received: Got 0xc0, expected 0x00 (Command has failed to execute on the tool)

Unable to enter programming mode. Verify device selection, interface settings, target power, security bit, and connections to the target device.

The device is powered separately and Atmel Studio read 5.0V. It is a virgin chip so it should be running at 1MHz. I have tried lowering the ISP clock frequency (what I found online), but that doesn't work. I also read to check all the connections but they are all good, so I have no idea why it wouldn't be working.

Atmel Studio version 6.0.634 on Windows 10
Driver for the avrisp mkii 12.0.0.0

Comment: Do you have a 10K resistor pulling RESET up?

Comment: @Cactus yes I have a 10k on the reset line